# Pass in Angular variables when starting app with node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I have this setting on my client side app.js in angular.js:

```
var options = {};
options.api = {};
options.api.base_url = "http://myDomainName.tld:8080";
```

I need to be able to change this on the CLI, when I am building my app.

My idea would be to do this with grunt.

Any other ideas how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [grunt-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-template) module.

Add your `app.js` file as `app.js.tpl`.

**app.js.tpl**

```
var options = {};
options.api = {};
options.api.base_url = "<%= base_url %>";
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        'template': {
            'process-js-template': {
                'options': {
                    'data': {
                        'base_url': 'http://myDomainName.tld:8080'
                        //Can also use 'base_url': grunt.option('base_url')
                        //If you wanted to take it from the CLI.
                        //EG: grunt default --base_url=http://myDomainName.tld:8080
                    }
                },
                'files': {
                    //The key being where you want to save the file.
                    'path/to/app.js': ['path/to/app.js.tpl']
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-template');
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'template'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Upvoted for the effort, however so far not working. Did you test?

Comment: @SirBenBenji I didn't test it, but there's no real reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: It does not get compiled, any way I found another solution (not putting env variables at all into my client/app.js). Yet - did you manage to get above working? You wrote "hypthetically it should work...."